# Nearest Neighbor's kneighbors method return different output for different sample sizes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, nearest-neighbor

I've built a NearestNeighbor model with [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#unsupervised-nearest-neighbors). Clusters seem fine when get clusters with kneighbors method just after fitting model.

```
    model = NearestNeighbors(n_jobs=-1, n_neighbors=5).fit(np.array(df))
    distance, indices = model.kneighbors(np.array(df))  ## one of the distances is always 0, as expected. And clusters are acceptable.
```

But when I save model and then read for train data, outputs are not acceptable.

```
     model = pickle.load(f)
     distance, indices = model.kneighbors(np.array(df))  ## same dataset, average/bad results. None of distances are 0.
```

And, biggest problem, indices and distances change according to df size.

```
      model = pickle.load(f)
      df_1 = df[df["id"] == "1"] # Trying for just one user
      distance, indices = model.kneighbors(np.array(df_1))  ## one row, same output for every user.
      df_2 = df[df["id"] == "2"]
      distance, indices = model.kneighbors(np.array(df_2)) ## same output

      df = df[df["id"] == "2" | df["id"] == "1"]
      distance, indices = model.kneighbors(np.array(df)) ## different output for both
```

Train/test dataset looks like this

```
feature1 | feature2 | feature3
   0          1          1
   1          1          1
   0          0          0
```

Why we train and save model if it's not possible use after with different dataset? Is this expected behavior of model or am I missing something?

Comment: `NearestNeighbors` is just evaluating distance between the samples in your df, so you should have the same results. Could you add a sample df and your save/load code to obtain a [Minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a horrible mistake I made, and I want to share the problem and solution. Very simple but it may be hard to see.

I read docs thousand times, and then noticed they use np.array but not DataFrame. Well, I used Dataframe for prediction and columns randomized. So, it was not working correctly.

If you have problem like that, be careful about numpy indexes!